# Html tags not formating inside c# string.format

Tags: c#, html, string.format

I am trying to send an email with formatted HTML inside the string and an argument.
my code is like this:

```
string title = "Big";
string text = "<p>email stuff with <b>important</b> {0} stuff</p>";
string.Format(text, title);


MailMessage msz = new MailMessage();
var studentEmail = "someplace@somewhere.net";


msz.To.Add(new MailAddress(studentEmail, "Someone"));

msz.From = new MailAddress(from);                                    

msz.Subject = "Subject";
msz.Body = bodyText;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

smtp.Send(msz);
```

I want to get in the email "email stuff with **important** Big stuff", However I am getting this in the email: `<p>email stuff with <b>important</b> {0} stuff</p>`

Comment: How are you sending the email?

Comment: You need to escape your text.

Comment: Cannot repro on a sample console app. It formats as `<p>email stuff with <b>important</b> Big stuff</p>`.

Comment: I am sending the email with smtp

Comment: Do you assign the returned value of `string.Format` to some variable? :)

Comment: I'm sure its just a typo and this isn't your issue; however, you appear to be missing a semicolon after the string title declaration.

Comment: @ChrisCruz Thanks, I edited the original post to fix it. It was a typo not the error in my app.  I also used your answer and it worked for the arguments however I am still getting the tags in my email.

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you are using to send the email? At least the creation of the objects related to email sending.

Comment: Can you share the actual code? In your example, `bodyText` is not defined.

Comment: @ChrisCruz Thank you! you solved my problem with the interpolation and the IsBodyHtml attribute set to true.

Comment: I'm surprised but glad that worked for you. Please mark as the answer and good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on providing sample code in the post - since obviously there is not problems with `String.Format` (assuming you assign value as you said in comment) you should not have added that part of the code to the post and instead use string constant... You've also presumably searched for way to send HTML mail (i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+send+mail+html) - so sample already should have `IsBodyHtml`... (creating high quality MCVE sometimes lead to solving question, but it is good thing unless for some reason you need many posts on SO)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually it will depend on how did you send the email.

You should store the text into `Body` part of a `MailMessage`

```
string title = "Big";
string text = "<p>email stuff with <b>important</b> {0} stuff</p>";
string.Format(text, title);


MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = "sender@abc.com");
message.To.Add("dummy@abc.com");
message.Subject = title;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = text;
```

With `IsBodyHtml = true`, it will help you to format all Html tag.

For sending:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient()
...
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: Since you've called attention to your code I had to vote on it too. Post  actually does not explain why OP had issues with `String.Format` and code in this post has exactly the same problem as original code - result of `String.Format` is ignored. Showing how to actually send HTML email is nice, but it is not what question is asking about (ignoring comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***string interpolation*** to add the value(s) you need directly:

```
string title = "Big"

// Now this value has your expected output.
string text = $"<p>email stuff with <b>important</b> {title} stuff</p>";
```